# Como aumentar a largura das colunas da tabela e ajustar a largura da janela modal do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Preciso ajustar duas coisas em uma janela Modal Bootstap/javascript:

1 - A largura e altura da janela modal;
2 - Os nome das colunas da tabela estão quebrando para uma nova linha e deformando a aparência. Preciso fazer com que cada coluna ajuste-se de acordo com os nomes.

Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="pessoaHistory" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Histórico de Alterações</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body scoll-tree" style="overflow-x: auto;">
                <p id="pessoaHistoryData"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".remove-row").on("click", function () {
            var pessoaId = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/pessoa-gerenciamento/pessoa-historico/" + pessoaId,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var formatHtml = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
                formatHtml += "<thead><th>Ação</th><th>Quando</th><th>Código</th><th>Natureza</th><th>Nome/Razão Social</th><th>Apelido/Nome Fantasia</th><th>Nascimento/Abertura</th><th>Sexo</th><th>Estado Civil</th><th>Pelo Usuário</th></thead>";

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var change = data[i];
                    formatHtml += "<tr>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.acao + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.quando + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.id + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.natureza + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.nomeCompletoRazaoSocial + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.apelidoNomeFantasia + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.nascimentoAbertura + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.sexo + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.estadoCivil + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "<td>" + change.quem + "</td>";
                    formatHtml += "</tr>";
                }
                formatHtml += "</table>";
                $("#pessoaHistoryData").html(formatHtml);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aumentar o tamanho do modal do Bootstrap, você pode usar normalmente css, por exemplo:

No código abaixo, olhe a classe que eu inseri na segunda DIV

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog bigModal"> //ATENÇÃO À CLASSE bigModal
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      seu header aqui
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
          seu body aqui
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      seu footer aqui
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

E depois você adiciona a classe bigModal em um arquivo css:

```
.bigModal{
   width: 85%
   height: 500px;
}
```

Ou você pode usar o estilo 'in-line':

...

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 85%; height: 500px;">
```

...

Mas de qualquer forma recomendo fortemente que você faça em uma folha de css separada para facilitar na manutenção do código

Sobre as colunas, o próprio Bootstrap já arruma a largura delas segundo seu conteúdo. Quando você aumentar a largura do modal como um todo, acredito que seu problema vai estar resolvido

Espero ter ajudado, um abraço

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus Alberghini!!! Funcionou 100% mano!!!

Comment: Magina cara, é um prazer. Keep Learning.